# Get Sibling Element of an Image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have

```
<a href="1.html">
    <img src = "image.jpg" class = "picture"/>
    <div class="desc"><p>Brief Description</p></div>
</a>

<a href="2.html">
    <img src = "image2.jpg" class = "picture"/>
    <div class="desc"><p>Brief Description</p></div>
</a>
```

How do I cycle through the pictures and alter the div accordingly?

So far I have something like:

```
var pictures = $('.picture');
(var a = 0; a < pictures.size(); a++){
    var description = (pictures.get(a)) (.siblings?)(.next?);
    //Do what I want with the description
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Jquery `.each()` to loop through the elements. And `.siblings()` to get the sibling of that element.

`$('.picture').each(function(){
  var description = $(this).siblings('div. desc').text();
  // Do what I want with the description
});`

Answer (score 2):

notice that `.get(a)` won't give you a jQuery set, but instead a plain object
https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

```js
var pictures = $('.picture');
pictures.each(function() {
    var description = $(this).next().html();
    //Do what I want with the description
    console.log(description);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="1.html">
    <img src = "image.jpg" class = "picture"/>
    <div class="desc"><p>Brief Description 1</p></div>
</a>

<a href="2.html">
    <img src = "image2.jpg" class = "picture"/>
    <div class="desc"><p>Brief Description 2</p></div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about selecting the description's `<p>` directly?

Like this:

`$('.picture .desc p').`...

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`next`](https://api.jquery.com/next/).

```
$('.picture').each(function(idx, picture){
    $(picture).next('.desc'); //this will select div.desc
});
```